# What do holy books say about inter-caste marriages?

Tags: scripture, marriage, caste-system

What do holy books say about inter-caste marriages? I heard somewhere that marriages between different castes causes **वर्ण संकर** (*Varna Samkar*) and our holy books don't support inter-caste marriages.

Is there any proof regarding this?

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9914/examples-of-anuloma-and-pratiloma-marriages

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7227/why-hinduism-wont-encourage-inter-caste-marriages doesn't provide any holy book reference.

Comment: First you need to know True Varna in Sanatana Dharma. Varna in Sanata Dharma depends on innate traits and Propensities. It depends only on one's Guna and nature. See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8218/3500) answer to know Varna System that existed in olden days.

Comment: @urfusion none of the answer there even accepted yet and doesn't got much praise too. No need to mention that in your question, its still a duplicate.

Comment: In Bhagavad Gita, [This sloka](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/1/40) from Arjuna and [this sloka](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3/24) from Krishna describes the issues with वर्ण संकर system. Try to read the Sanskrit part of the scripture. I am upvoting your Q, as it doesn't deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

The Agni Purana speaks about inter caste marriages in details while talking about the Manus & the Varnashrama Dharma(the Dhrama of the 4 classes of society & the 4 stages of life).

Quoting  from [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/agnipurana-6.htm) page,

> An anuloma marriage is a marriage where the husband is from a higher
>   class than the wife. The offspring of such a marriage belong to the
>   mother’s class. A pratiloma marriage is a marriage where the wife is
>   from a higher class than the husband. Chandalas were born this way
>   from brahmana women, Sutas from kshatriya women, Devalas from vaishya
>   women, Pukkashas from kshatriya women and Magadhas from vaishya women.
>   Chandalas are executioners, Sutas charioteers, Devalas guards,
>   Pukkashas hunters and Magadhas bards. Chandalas should live outside
>   the villages and should not touch those belonging to any other class.

So,naturally,a Pratiloma marriage is looked down upon and prohibited specially those which results in Chnadalas as offsprings.