# What do the scriptures say about inter-caste marriage?

Tags: scripture, marriage, caste-system

Please don't hijack the question with other related things like equality and caste.

Only post answers with sources to scriptures that particularly talk about inter caste marriage.

Sources are necessary. Don't make claims without links to sources.

Cite sources with excerpts and explanation.

Comment: There is a question already asked [Why Hinduism won't encourage inter-caste marriages?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7227/3500)

Comment: Related: [What do our scriptures speaks on the “ Caste based discrimination ” for marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18433/1049)